# How to extract xvalues and yvalues from a kdeplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, kdeplot

Given that I have a `seaborn.kdeplot` I want to extract the `x` and `y` points. Based on similar questions I have tried the following:

```
points = sns.kdeplot(targets, shade=True, label='train').get_lines()[0].get_data()
x      = points[0]
y      = points[1]
```

But I'm getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm using `seaborn==0.12.2` and `matplotlib==3.7.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you request `shade=True` (use `fill=True` in the latest seaborn versions), the output axes object does not contain a `Line2D` object (it instead contains a [`PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection)). If you remove the `shade=True`, you be able to extract the data in the way that you give:

```py
ax = sns.kdeplot(targets, label='train')
points = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()
x = points[0]
y = points[1]
```